# Set of products from multiplication table using set notation

Tags: notation

Just a quick question, if I have a set of tuples named $N$, what is the notation to generate a set ($M$) with the product of each tuple contained in set $N$.

Current markup:
$$N=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$$
$$N^2=\{<n_i,n_j>|\,n_i,n_j\in N\}$$
$$M=\{1*1,1*2,...,9*8,9*9\}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard notation, so what ever notation you invent be sure to explain yourself (define it properly). I might use $M = N * N$ for the occasion, using the variables you used.